# Value of element in my array always undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, in Javascript, i create an Array and i push some datas :

```
var arrayAddress = new Array();
arrayAddress.push(data1);
arrayAddress.push(data2);
//etc...
```

With a `console.log(arrayAddress)`, i have :

```
[]              
0   48.8557669      
1   2.3587343       
2   "Paris"     
3   "France"    
4   "75004"
```

How can i retrieve an element in this array ? If i try `arrayAddress[n]` i have "`undefined`"...

Comment: Are you sure `arrayAddress` is filled before you try to access its elements? (Keep asynchrony in mind, if you fill the array in an asynchronous function, the results won't be available right away.)

Comment: I push all datas in the event "done" of an $.ajax in jquery

Comment: @Clément, there you are. I suppose you access the elements before the async function has finished running. You should also do that from the `done` callback.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Then you need to call a callback in that `done` event, as javascript will continue and not wait for the ajax to finish itself.

Comment: Yeah thanks you ;) I have forget ajax is async.... :)

Answer (score 0):

may be it can help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arrayAddress = new Array();
 var data1 = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
 var data2 = [ "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" ];
  arrayAddress.push(data1);
  arrayAddress.push(data2);
 for(i=0; i < arrayAddress.length; i++){
  var newarrobj = arrayAddress[i];
  //alert(arrayAddress[i]);
  for(j=0; j < newarrobj.length; j++){
   alert(newarrobj[j])
  }
}
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ronjon/nyDLT/)

Answer (score -1):

try this `arrayAddress.at(n)`. hope it will help.

Comment: Error : arrayAddress.at is not a function